# How to access sqlite file inside the xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to IOS development and I want to know how to access sqlite file inside xcode project. In other files they do this:

```
NSString *path = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"image" ofType: @"png"];
```

but when I'm trying this line of code it doesn't work in sqlite extension.

Comment: What is the full name of your sqlite file?

Comment: `NSString *path = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"myDatabase" ofType: @"sqlite"];`. Does it work ?

Comment: By access do you mean just load it (which KudoCC has told you how to do), or actually opening it and pulling data ?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

Answer (score 2):

[ios_sqlite_database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm)

[ABSQLite](https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite) - sample project

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;

        // Get the documents directory
        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

        // Build the path to the database file
        databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];

        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
        {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                        char *errMsg;
                        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

                        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
                        {
                                status.text = @"Failed to create table";
                        }

                        sqlite3_close(contactDB);

                } else {
                        status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
                }
        }

        [filemgr release];
        [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

[sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)

Comment: I don't want to manually create my database and tables by using stringByAppendingPathComponent. I have my own db and it's stored inside my project in xcode. All I want is to access my db inside my xcode project

Comment: if you want like use coredata